# Button color change on click or hover

Tags: xaml, button, maui, winui

I added a button component in my application, and I am expecting it to change the color when user hovers on it or click it.

But looks like that's not the default behavior of the button.

Is there a way to get that behavior maybe by setting some attribute?

Comment: [VIsual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve `Focused` is not the same as hover, if you hover the mouse on the button it won't make it "focused and thus even if you define visual state "Focused" it won't be triggered

Comment: @Cfun - Yes. Q mentions two situations, "click it" is supported by VIsual States. There is an open issue in github re focus.